# Add new array values to existing array position

Tags: php, arrays, addition, exists

I have array which is presenting like this:

```
        $array = array (
        "list" => array(
            "serwer-1" => 3
        ),
        "servers" => array(
            3 => array(
                "msg" => "{'some data': 123123121313}",
                "status" => 200
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I want add new items to $array['list'] for example:

```
        array (
        "list" => array(
            "serwer-1" => 3
            //NEW DATA HERE
            "serwer-2" => 7,
        ),
        "servers" => array(
            3 => array(
                "msg" => "{'some data': 123123121313}",
                "status" => 200
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Maybe it's trivial, but I haven't any idea how to do this - I have bad day today :(

Comment: `$array['list']['serwer-2'] = 7;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a key-value pair to an existing array just do it like the key exists there.

```
$array["list"]["serwer-2"] = 7;
```

Then you will get desired result.